# Placing Order Without inventory Check

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6

For some orders placing time don't want to check the inventory details is available and qty details but product manage stock is YES

Comment: you can set allow backorder to yes

Comment: @Murtuza Zabuawala but i want to manage stock yes and backorder also restricted i want to place an order from the cron job on that time no need to check